# Spinner Adapter from LiveData

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to construct `ArrayAdapter` for `Spinner` from `LiveData<List<T>>` instead of normally `List<T>`?

What is the best practice to bind a ViewModel's LiveData returned value to a `Spinner`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If It is exactly what do you mean, so:

```
class MyVM : ViewModel() {
  ...
  private val mSpinnerData = MutableLiveData<List<String>>()
  ...
  fun fetchSpinnerItems(): LiveData<List<String>> {
    //fetch data
    mSpinnerData.value = <some fetched list of Strings>
    return mSpinnerData
  }
}
```

And after in your activity/fragment:

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
  private lateinit var mViewModel: MyVM
  ...
  override fun onCreate(outState: Bundle?) {
    //initialize your view model here...
    mViewModel.fetchSpinnerItems().observe(this, Observer { spinnerData ->
      val spinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerData)
      mSpinner.adapter = spinnerAdapter
    })
  ...
}
```

Comment: Gah, I forgot to mention I code in Java instead of Kotlin >.>

Comment: Is LiveData iterable?

Comment: can we set listlivedata to spinner inside viewmodel using binding adapter?

Comment: @skyshine, yes, of course! We can use also binding adapter for the purpose.